# Can we increase the limit of ACL rules in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, acl, amazon-vpc

Documentation says:
Rules per network ACL : 20
This is the one-way limit for a single network ACL, where the limit for ingress rules is 20, and the limit for egress rules is 20.

I want to know can we increase the rules limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are just soft limits - just raise a support ticket for limit increase and you would be all set.

You can navigate to EC2 -> Limits in the side bar.

[image]

Comment: What is the hard limit, i icon says its 40

Comment: When I ran out of rules, I got it raised to "Current Limit 40" [ 40 inbound & 40 outbound ] - I am not sure if that is what it means or have I reached the max.

Comment: Can you please tell me, is there any possible way to whitelist outbound based on hostname

Comment: Host Name not possible - IP - CIDR is only possible.

Comment: Is there any way to automatically update the outbound? Can you please share it

Comment: I don't think there is an out of the box way - but you can certainly write script or code to perform that.

Comment: The UI has changed a little since your answer @NaveenVijay . Clicking 'Limits' takes you to the Limits page. Near the top-right hand corner of the limit page is a drop-down menu which defaults to "All limits". One entry in that drop-down in "Networking", where you can see the limit involved - "Rules per Network ACL"